# When to release when using "withCompletionHandler"

Tags: objective-c

I'm using a block to do stuff when the data is fetched, but when do I release the array which I created before?

```
GKLeaderboard *leaderboardRequest = [[GKLeaderboard alloc] init];
if (leaderboardRequest != nil) {
    [leaderboardRequest loadScoresWithCompletionHandler: ^(NSArray *scores, NSError *error) {
        // do stuff
        // release leaderboardRequest here?
    }];
}
// or here?
```

It seems to work on another thread, so I'm concerned that if I release it at the end, I might interfere with the completion code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is safe to to release the leaderboardRequest because the block will make sure that the local variable is retained until the completion of your code. leaderboardRequest will be immutable unless defined with `__block` but I doubt you will need to change the reference.

Read the [Blocks Programming Topic](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/Blocks/Articles/bxVariables.html).

```
GKLeaderboard *leaderboardRequest = [[GKLeaderboard alloc] init];
if (leaderboardRequest != nil) {
    [leaderboardRequest loadScoresWithCompletionHandler: ^(NSArray *scores, NSError *error) {
        // do stuff
        // release leaderboardRequest here? NO!
    }];
}
// Here
[leaderboardRequest release];
```

Comment: Thanks - I've read it & sort of understand some of it. It's how I had coded it anyway, but it's good to know why you do something!