# Objective C - block question?

Tags: objective-c, grand-central-dispatch, objective-c-blocks

I have the following method

```
+ (NSString*)getMeMyString
{
   NSString *result;
   dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        result = [ClassNotThreadSafe getString];
    });
   return result;
}
```

How can i make the block to do it's job synchronously, so that it doesn't return the result before it was retreived?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are calling `dispatch_async` which dispatches your block asynchronously. Try using `dispatch_sync` or `dispatch_main` if your goal is to block the main thread.

```
+ (NSString*)getMeMyString
{
   __block NSString *result;
   dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        result = [ClassNotThreadSafe getString];
    });
   return result;
}
```

[Grand Central Dispatch](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/Reference/reference.html) Reference

Comment: Yes he is! I will make my answer more relevant for his goal.

Comment: NOTE: [ClassNotThreadSafe getString] this method is not thread safe that's why I am trying to use a block.

Comment: @Joe: it should be `__block NSString *result;`, otherwise `result` is a const entity within the block and can't be modified.

Comment: I see, is your goal to always run this code on the main thread or just have it synchronized across all threads that access it. I ask because you may be able able to accomplish what you are doing with a static object and @synchronized block.

Comment: @BJ Homer: Thanks again, that was full of fail because I just answered the same type of question for someone http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5566892/when-to-release-when-using-withcompletionhandler/5567591#5567591

Comment: this is exactly what I want because I want it to run on the main thread, I don't need synchronized in this situation. thanks

Comment: and also thanks for pointing out "__block". Figuring out why the code in my block wouldn't detect the variable was going on my nerve

Answer (score 4):

Use `dispatch_sync` instead of `dispatch_async` - then the current thread will be blocked until the block has finished executing on the main thread.

Comment: This. Also, you'll want to declare your result string as `__block` so your object reference is passed back out.

Answer (score 2):

Since it seems like you want to perform a method on a different thread and get a return value, why don't you use an NSInvocation?

```
SEL theSelector;
NSMethodSignature *aSignature;
NSInvocation *anInvocation;

theSelector = @selector(getString);
aSignature = [ClassNotThreadSafe instanceMethodSignatureForSelector:theSelector];
anInvocation = [NSInvocation invocationWithMethodSignature:aSignature];
[anInvocation setSelector:theSelector];

NSString *result;

[anInvocation performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(invoke) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];
[anInvocation getReturnValue:result];
```

Comment: This is really interesting and useful, but seems to be too much work for this situation :)